# JavaEE with WildFly: Rest Resource not found - why?

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, wildfly

Im trying to run just a simple REST-Application with WildFly-Application Server in background. But the REST-Call gives me permanently the `Not Found`-Error.

Here is my `RestService`-class:

```
@Path("/rest")
public class RestService {


    @GET
    @Path("/hello")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response helloWorld() {

        try {
            System.out.println("ABCDEF");
            return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity("hello world!").build();
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(throwable).build();
        }
    }
}
```

With Rest-Configuration-File :

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class JaxRsActivator extends Application {
}
```

and here are my Configuration-Files:

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.java</groupId>
    <artifactId>JavaEE</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>9</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>9</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>javaee</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">
    <display-name>REST</display-name>
</web-app>
```

jboss-web.xml:

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>services</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

and my Project structure:

[image]

I want to invoke my Rest-Service via following url:

http://127.0.0.1:8080/services/rest/hello

But it gives Not Found-Error - what is here the problem?

Comment: Is application server configured to run on localhost?

Comment: Do server logs say that the application is successfully deployed? Can you access any other resource in the .war (like static files, jsp, servlets)? Does `http://127.0.0.1:8080/services` return `index.html`? Is jax-rs enabled in the server-config file you're using?

Comment: yes it returns the index.html-web page...yes and server.logs says:[2018-04-29 07:36:01,198] Artifact JavaEE:war: Artifact is deployed successfully...how i found out if jax-rs is enabled or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error:

project structure is wrong: It has to be `web` and not `webapp`.